# After the use of smote (oversampling) in pipeline not getting result

Tags: python, smote

after the deployment of smote library on target columns still showing the imbalance target result.code is running successful but not showing the smote deployment results.
y_train.value_counts():

False    538
True      38
Name: isLegendary, dtype: int64

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer #apply trnasformation on columns
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline as imbpipeline

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='auto',random_state=42)

prepro = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False, drop='first'), ["Type_1", "Type_2", "Color", "Egg_Group_1", "Body_Style"]),
        ('ft', FunctionTransformer(func=np.log1p), ['Total', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp_Atk', 'Sp_Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Pr_Male', 'Height_m', 'Weight_kg']),
        ('scaler', MinMaxScaler(), ['Total', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp_Atk', 'Sp_Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Pr_Male', 'Height_m', 'Weight_kg'])
    ],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap= True,criterion='gini',max_depth=15,max_features='log2',n_estimators= 10,verbose=False)


# Create the imbalanced-learn pipeline
pipeline = imbpipeline([
    ('preprocessor', prepro),
    ('smote', smote),
    ('model',model)
])
# Fit the pipeline on the data
pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)

i am expecting that it should convert imbalance into balance class:-
y_train.value_counts():

False    538
True     538
Name: isLegendary, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

[The code is running successful but not converting it into balanced class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H6Kq.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.